# Need help with reinstall

Tags: system-installation

I have bootable usb with 12.04lts in it.and a corrupt 11.10 in my pc.no windows/or mac only ubuntu.need help with re-install.how do i go about it?

Comment: What computer do you have. Does your computer support boot from USB

Comment: i have a sony vaio only 2 years old so im pretty sure it does

Comment: What *exactly* do you need help with? Please be more specific in your original question, and we'll be able to help you more. :)

Comment: bootable usb doesnt take me to installer

Comment: im basically looking for a way to completely remove 11.10 and then install 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is going into bios( I don't know which key it is). In there, where it says boot order, change it to `usb` or `removable devices`(or however it says it in there) When you boot in the live USB, I imagine that since Ubuntu 11.10 got corrupted, that you will first want to save any data(files, pictures, folders, etc.) If not just go straight into the installation

Hope this helps you!

Comment: yes yes thank you.got it working just didnt know the key and plus 11.04 wasnt working till i plugged in the usb so i thought well it was workign and then it updated to 11.10

Comment: shouldve just asked before going through sites and apt-get update && upgrade dpkg -ing through the night -.-

Answer (score 1):

Enter your laptops bios screen (probley F2 on the sony screen, should tell you which button if its different at the bottom corner of the screen) and find the boot options.

Set it to boot from usb, then insert the 12.04 usb and reboot.

It will boot to the usb. Then when the install completes set you boot option back to th HDD (might be called SATA), reboot again and Ubuntu will start.

Hope that what you need.